# Selecionar múltiplas linhas com PHP JSON

Tags: php, json

Estou usando `SELECT` para coletar múltiplas linhas da minha base de dados.

Utilizando o formato de consulta abaixo eu tenho o resultado esperado.

```
while ($this->result = $this->pQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $this->json[] = $this->result;
}
```

resultado:

```
[
    {
        "evaluate_rq_id" : "10",
        "evaluate_rq_user_id" :"5", 
        "evaluate_rq_client" : "rrv@hotmail.com",
        "evaluate_rq_comment" : "Por favor, nos avalie.", 
        "evaluate_rq_date" : "2014-12-27 22:21:23"
    },
    {
        "evaluate_rq_id" : "11",
        "evaluate_rq_user_id" : "5",
        "evaluate_rq_client" : "mh@hotmail.com",
        "evaluate_rq_comment" : "Por favor, nos avalie.",
        "evaluate_rq_date" : "2014-12-27 22:23:33"
    },
    { 
        "evaluate_rq_id" : "12", 
        "evaluate_rq_user_id" : "5", 
        "evaluate_rq_client" :"mh@hotmail.com",
        "evaluate_rq_comment" : "Por favor, nos avalie.",
        "evaluate_rq_date" : "2014-12-28 10:45:05"
    }
```

]

Utilizando este formato eu tenho somente 1 linha de retorno.

```
while($this->result = $this->pQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    foreach($this->result as $row) {
        $this->json['evaluate_rq_id']      = $row['evaluate_rq_id'];
        $this->json['evaluate_rq_user_id'] = $row['evaluate_rq_user_id'];
        $this->json['evaluate_rq_client']  = $row['evaluate_rq_client'];
        $this->json['evaluate_rq_comment'] = $row['evaluate_rq_comment'];
        $this->json['evaluate_rq_date']    = $row['evaluate_rq_date'];
    }   
}
```

resultado:

```
{
    "evaluate_rq_id": "12",
    "evaluate_rq_user_id": "5",
    "evaluate_rq_client": "mh@hotmail.com",
    "evaluate_rq_comment": "Por favor, nos avalie.",
    "evaluate_rq_date": "2014-12-28 10:45:05"
}
```

A minha ideia em utilizar o segundo formato é configurar o campo *date* para o o formato `d-m-Y` antes de gerar o resultado no formato `JSON`, conforme abaixo:

```
$this->json['evaluate_rq_date'] = date("d-m-Y",  strtotime($row['evaluate_rq_date']));
```

Alguma idéia como gerar múltiplas linhas usando o segundo formato?

Comment: Podes clicar para aceitar a resposta que resolva o problema.

Answer (score 3):

O segundo formato também percorre todas as linhas, porém, aparece somente a última porque em todo loop você está atribuindo novo valor para as variáveis.

Usando assim já seria o suficiente para formatar a data como está querendo e o conteúdo de `$this->json` será todas as linhas:

```
while($this->result = $this->pQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $this->result['evaluate_rq_date'] = date("d-m-Y",  strtotime($row['evaluate_rq_date']));
    $this->json[] = $this->result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A segunda forma está fazendo corretamente oque você quer.

O problema está ao extrair os dados do banco, pois você está extraindo todos de uma vez ao invés de um a um.

Experimente a seguinte alteração no segundo método:

De:

```
while($this->result = $this->pQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
```

Para:

```
while($this->result = $this->pQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
```

Desta forma você vai extrair cada linha do banco corretamente.

Comment: Consegui executar com o que foi colocado pelo Antony.. Grato pela ajuda.